# What is the complexity of finding some vector without zero entries in the column space of a given matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, computational-complexity

Let $A \in k^{m \times n}$ be a matrix over the finite field $k$. Assume that we know that there is **some** $x = (x_1 \ldots x_n)^T \in k^n$ in the column space of $A$ such that $x_i \neq 0$ for all $i = 1,\ldots,n$. But we **do not know** the values $x_i$.

What is the complexity of finding an instance of such $x$ (which one is irrelevant)? If we knew the values $x_1,\ldots,x_n \in k$, then the complexity is that of solving the linear equation system $Ay = x$.

**Edit:** Maybe there is some connection to linear codes and finding an instance of a code with maximal weight. But I am not familiar with those things.

Comment: Are you trying to find $\vec{x}$ or $\vec{y}$?  In the second paragraph, if you know the $x_i$'s, why do you need to solve for $\vec{y}$?  You already have your point in the column space.

Comment: @MichaelBurr The question is about finding an instance of $x$! But if we knew the coordinates of such an $x$ (which we don't), the task is as hard as solving the equation system $Ay=x$.